# Rails cocoon nested form: undefined method `reflect_on_association' for NilClass:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

I am trying to build a form with nested resources in my rails 4 app. I am using the cocoon gem. Each step will have substeps, and I'd like to allow the user to add as many substeps to the form and he/she would like.

Step.rb

```
class Step < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :substeps
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :substeps
```

Substep.rb

```
class Substep < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :step
```

form code

```
<%= form_for :step, :url => steps_path do |f| %>
  <%= text_field(:step, :title, :value => '', class: 'fly-input input_info', placeholder: 'Process Title', id: 'step_form_title') %>
  <%= text_field(:step, :description, :value => '', class: 'fly-input input_info', placeholder: 'Process Description', id: 'step_form_description') %>
  <%= hidden_field :step, :known %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :experiment, @experiment.id %>
  <%= f.fields_for :substep do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.text_field :description %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to_add_association 'Add substep', f, :substeps %>
  <%= f.submit "Done", class: "main_button" %>
<% end %>
```

When I do this, I get an error reading:
"undefined method `reflect_on_association' for NilClass:Class" on this line

```
<%= link_to_add_association 'Add substep', f, :substeps %>
```

Any thoughts on my problem?

***EDIT***
Changed text_field to ff.text_field based on Pavan's suggestion

Comment: To which line the error is pointing to?

Comment: The error is on the '<%= link_to_add_association 'Add substep', f, :substeps %>' line

Comment: Can you include code for `link_to_add_association`?

Comment: Try changing `<%= f.fields_for :substep do |ff| %>` to `<%= f.fields_for :substeps do |ff| %>`

Comment: Your point @Pavan is correct but then also `<%= text_field :substep, :description %>` needs to be fixed to `<%= ff.text_field :substep, :description %>`

Comment: @Pavan - I tried changing it to substeps, and still receiving the error

Comment: @MichalSzyndel I made your modification, and I get "undefined method `merge' for :description:Symbol" both with and without @Pavan's suggestion

Comment: Ok. now try changing `<%= link_to_add_association 'Add substep', f, :substeps %>` to `<%= link_to_add_association 'Add substep', ff, :substeps %>`

Comment: I changed <%= ff.text_field :substep, :description %> to <%= ff.text_field  :description %> . It removed the merge error, and went back to the original error

Comment: Great, so now please show us source of `link_to_add_association` so we can fix the original error

Comment: Shouldn't the `link_to_add_association` be inside the `fields_for` block?

Comment: @Pavan changing that gives 'undefined local variable or method `ff''. It's not defined after the end of the ff form.

Comment: @MichalSzyndel it's defined in the cocoon gem: https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/blob/master/lib/cocoon/view_helpers.rb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cocoon expects that you provide a form object as second parameter, as you do, but also expects that this second parameter will have actually Rails model instance as attribute `f.object`.

Your form is created just with model name so `form_for :step` so Cocoon raises an exception.

To solve this you should change it to `form_for @step` where `@step` can be `Step.new` or any other `Step` instance.

Comment: For some reason, my substep parameters are not being passed to my controller, but that is a separate issue I suppose.

Comment: @Ron You need to change `<%= ff.text_field :substep, :description %>` to `<%= ff.text_field :description %>` to get it passed correctly to the controller.

Comment: It is still only grabbing the first step listed, and not the steps created with the Add button

Comment: @Ron I think you should ask a new question for that, this one got really messy already

Comment: I made a second one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34859649/rails-cocoon-nested-form-only-receiving-one-first-nested-attribute