# Rails cocoon nested form only receiving one first nested attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cocoon-gem

I am trying to build a form with nested resources in my rails 4 app. I am using the cocoon gem. Each step will have substeps, and I'd like to allow the user to add as many substeps to the form and he/she would like.

Step.rb

```
class Step < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :substeps
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :substeps
```

Substep.rb

```
class Substep < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :step
```

form code

```
<%= form_for Step.new, :url => steps_path do |f| %>
  <%= text_field(:step, :title, :value => '', class: 'fly-input input_info', placeholder: 'Process Title', id: 'step_form_title') %>
  <%= text_field(:step, :description, :value => '', class: 'fly-input input_info', placeholder: 'Process Description', id: 'step_form_description') %>
  <%= hidden_field :step, :known %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :experiment, @experiment.id %>
  <%= f.fields_for :substep do |ff| %>
    <%= render "substep_fields", :f => ff %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to_add_association 'Add substep', f, :substeps %>
  <%= f.submit "Done", class: "main_button" %>
<% end %>
```

_substep_fields.html.erb

```
<div class='nested-fields'>
  <%= f.text_field :description %>
</div>
```

steps_controller.rb

```
def step_params
  params.require(:step).permit(:title, :description, :known, substeps_attributes: [:id, :description, :action, :_destroy])
end
```

I can see the first input, and add second, third, so on inputs for multiple substeps. The problem is, only the first substep's description will be passed to the controller:

```
(byebug) params
params
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xxx", "step"=>{"title"=>"Test Title", "description"=>"Test Desc", "known"=>"-1", "substep"=>{"description"=>"Substep1"}}, "experiment"=>"64", "commit"=>"Done", "controller"=>"steps", "action"=>"create"}
```

Any thoughts on my problem?

***EDIT***
Sharing HTML generated after adding two substeps

```
<form class="new_step" id="new_step" action="/steps" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
<input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="xxxx">
  <input value="" class="fly-input input_info ui-autocomplete-input" placeholder="Process Title" id="step_form_title" type="text" name="step[title]" data-hasqtip="6" aria-describedby="qtip-6" autocomplete="off">
  <label class="fly-label classic is-active" for="classic">Description</label>
  <input value="" class="fly-input input_info" placeholder="Process Description" id="step_form_description" type="text" name="step[description]" data-hasqtip="7" aria-describedby="qtip-7">
  <input type="hidden" name="step[known]" id="step_known" value="-1">
  <input type="hidden" name="experiment" id="experiment" value="76">
</form>
  <div class="nested-fields">
    <input type="text" name="step[substeps_attributes][1453146839656][description]" id="step_substeps_attributes_1453146839656_description">
  </div>
  <div class="nested-fields">
    <input type="text" name="step[substeps_attributes][1453146844032][description]" id="step_substeps_attributes_1453146844032_description">
  </div>
  <div class="" id="customprocess_processsteps">
    <a class="main_button add_fields" data-association="substep" data-associations="substeps" data-association-insertion-template="<div class='nested-fields'>
  <input type=&quot;text&quot; name=&quot;step[substeps_attributes][new_substeps][description]&quot; id=&quot;step_substeps_attributes_new_substeps_description&quot; />
</div>" href="#">Add substeps</a>
    <button aria-label="Close reveal" class="close-button" data-close="" type="button">
    </button>
  </div>
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Done" class="main_button">
```

Comment: I guess you fixed the problem mentioned by @BroiSatse. Can you add html that is generated after you add a few substeps?

Comment: @MichalSzyndel added the HTML generated

Comment: Interesting, it should work in my opinion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to match exactly the name of the association within `fields_for`. Change this:

```
<%= f.fields_for :substep do |ff| %>
```

To

```
<%= f.fields_for :substeps do |ff| %>
```

EDIT: Cocoon expects a strict DOM structure to work, try changing

```
<%= f.fields_for :substep do |ff| %>
  <%= render "substep_fields", :f => ff %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to_add_association 'Add substep', f, :substeps %>
```

To:

```
<div id="substeps">
  <%= f.fields_for :substep do |ff| %>
    <%= render "substep_fields", :f => ff %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="links">
    <%= link_to_add_association 'Add substep', f, :substeps %>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I remember correctly, only wrapper around `link_to_add_association` is required, the most top-level wrapper is just nice to have.

Comment: I renamed it to :substeps, and then renamed my partial to _substeps_fields.html.erb to match. I'm now getting an error on the link_to_add_association of 'Missing partial experiments/_substep_fields,'

Comment: Without renaming the partial, the input wasn't displayed initially and the second/third inputs which were added still didn't pass in params.

Comment: You shouldn't rename the partial, the fact that initially it was empty is correct (as there were no associated objects to display). Can you show what you're getting in params after that change?

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks. I'm still not getting the two inputs I'm adding with the Add substep button: 
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xxxx", "step"=>{"title"=>"New test title", "description"=>"New test desc", "known"=>"-1"}, "experiment"=>"65", "commit"=>"Done", "controller"=>"steps", "action"=>"create"}

Comment: Does it work after you fixed the issues? The HTML looks like it should pass the data accordingly.

Comment: @RichPeck - According to html it shouldn't - those fields are outside of the form. No idea why though

Comment: loooool and now I look like a noob :) It's probably an issue with how Cocoon is appending the fields?

Comment: @SlimReaper - Answer updated, should work fine now. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two changes you need to make. One is as BroiSatse wrote, changing

```
<%= f.fields_for :substep do |ff| %>
```

to

```
<%= f.fields_for :substeps do |ff| %>
```

and second, changing

```
params.require(:step).permit(..., substeps_attributes: [:id, :description, :action, :_destroy])
```

to

```
params.require(:step).permit(..., substeps_attributes: [[:id, :description, :action, :_destroy]])
```

Comment: Getting the same parameters unfortunately: 
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xxx", "step"=>{"title"=>"Test Step Title", "description"=>"Test Step Desc", "known"=>"-1"}, "experiment"=>"82", "commit"=>"Done", "controller"=>"steps", "action"=>"create"}

Comment: And my strong params: step_params
{"title"=>"Test Step Title", "description"=>"Test Step Desc", "known"=>"-1"}

Comment: AFAIK, second change is not required. At least my apps are working fine without double brackets